# How do I reinstall Firefox's default certificates?

Tags: firefox

I am using Firefox. I think some of the SSL certificates are corrupted.

I want to delete all certificates that I have currently in Firefox and reinstall Mozilla's default certificates, but I want to maintain the rest of my profile data (bookmarks, history, etc.).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What makes you think the certificates are corrupted?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Whats exactly your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open Firefox and in the menu, head to Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> View Certificates.

You can view, manage and delete your certificates from there.

Additionally, assuming you're using Windows Vista+, you can head to `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles` and delete (or rename) the `cert8.db` and `cert_override.txt` files in each of the profiles.

More info [here](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1254), [here](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=398987) and [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/749035).